# formula for conversion from hdpi to ldpi/mdpi/xhdpi

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image that is x pixels wide and y pixels high.

It displays just fine in on android hdpi portrait displays

Is there a formula I can use to convert x and y to the appropriate dimensions for ldpi, mdpi and xhdp displays for portrait and landscape?

Comment: Hmm.. `ldpi => 0.5*hdpi` || `mdpi => ((2 * hdpi) / 3)` || `xhdpi => ((4 * hdpi) / 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple methods I always have handy in a static Utils class:

```
public static int convertDp2Px(Context context, int dps) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    float pixels = dps * (scale / 160.0f);
    return (int) pixels;
}

public static float convertPx2Dp(Context context, int pixels) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    float dps = pixels / (scale / 160.0f);
    return dps;
}
```

And...from this link:
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

To generate these images, you should start with your raw resource in vector format and generate the images for each density using the following size scale:

xhdpi: 2.0
hdpi: 1.5
mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
ldpi: 0.75